# How to give a 410 error on all files not found?

Tags: .htaccess

My site was hacked some time before and we caught this issue and cleaned the site but now we are dealing with a ton of fake, bogus links created by the hackers on other website pointing to pages that do not exists on our server.

We have our `htaccess` setup to deliver a custom 404 page for any search bots and/or visitor who may come to our site from a bogus link.  `Google` is finding these bogus link out there on the web and keeps trying to index them.

I have read that I should be giving a `410 (gone)` code to `google` instead of a `404 (not found)` because Google treats the `410` more strongly then a `404`. My problem is that I do not know how to deliver a `410 error` code instead of a `404 error` to `google` from my `htaccess`.

If anyone can help me with this I would really be appreciative. Again, I want to give a `410` code for ALL files that are not found and direct a user to a special page stating that the file they requested is gone.

Answer (score 1):

Response 410 code for the files not exists:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L,R=410]
```

Setting a custom 410 error page like this:

```
ErrorDocument 410 /410.html
```